# IPv6 support in Java2ME

Tags: java, java-me

It seems that Sun's Java ME SDK doesn't support IPv6. Am I right? I've made such conclusion from javax.microedition.io.SocketConnection description:

> ..The host may be specified as a fully qualified host name or IPv4 number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 is supported in [Foundation Profile 1.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/fp1.1.2/jsr219/index.html) of JavaME.  It is listed as one of the new features, and if you look in the `java.net` package there is an `Inet6Address` class.

So, if you need IPv6, you may need to upgrade your JavaME platform.  But note that the copyright date on the FP 1.1.2 Javadoc is 2006 ... and a bit more digging reveals that the IPv6 changes were actually made in FP 1.1 which was finalized in 08/02/2004.  From that perspective, any JavaME platform with FP that doesn't support IPv6 is 9+ years out of date.

Maybe something like this ...

[image: Old school guy with old school mobile phone]

---

> And what about MIDP 2 profile?

MIDP 2.0 supports IPv6; see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/package-summary.html#package_description) ... and search the page for "IPv6".  (I don't know if this guarantees that every implementation of MIDP 2.0 supports IPv6, but if your vendor doesn't ... it is probably time to ditch them.)